# Why am I getting a syntax error when trying to use -v flag for variables in psql command?

Tags: zsh, psql

I'm trying to use the following psql command in a zsh shell to send a query to a database:

```
psql -Atx $mydburl -v myvar=1 -c "SELECT :myvar"
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: SELECT :myvar
               ^
```

However, when I use a pipe, this works just fine:

```
echo "SELECT :myvar" | psql -Atx $mydburl -v myvar=1
```

And it produces the expected result of:

```
?column?|1
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [as documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> `-c command`
> [...]
> `command` must be either a command string that is completely parsable by the server (i.e., it contains no psql-specific features), or a single backslash command.